# Неправильная выгрузка поля LocalDate при выгрузке ArrayList<CustomObject> из SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, localdate

```
Пользовательский объект

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class CountingEntry implements Parcelable
{
    private String purchase;
    private int cost;
    private LocalDate dateOfpurchase;
    public void SetPurchase(String purchase_)
    {
        purchase = purchase_;
    }
    public void SetCost(int cost_)
    {
        cost = cost_;
    }
    public void SetDateOfPurchase(LocalDate dateOfpurchase_)
    {
        dateOfpurchase = dateOfpurchase_;
    }
    public String GetPurchase()
    {
        return purchase;
    }
    public int GetCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public LocalDate GetDateOfPurchase()
    {
        return dateOfpurchase;
    }
    public CountingEntry(String purchase_,int cost_,LocalDate dateOfpurchase_)
    {
        this.purchase = purchase_;
        this.cost = cost_;
        this.dateOfpurchase = dateOfpurchase_;
    }
    private CountingEntry(Parcel in)
    {
        purchase = in.readString();
        cost = in.readInt();
        dateOfpurchase = LocalDate.parse(in.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(this.purchase);
        dest.writeInt(this.cost);
        dest.writeString(this.dateOfpurchase.toString());
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CountingEntry> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CountingEntry>()
    {
        public CountingEntry createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new CountingEntry(in);
        }

        public CountingEntry[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new CountingEntry[size];
        }
    };
}
Функции сохранения и загрузки
if(id == R.id.action_SaveCountingEntries)
        {
            if(!countingEntries.isEmpty())
            {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(countingEntries);
                editor.putString("MyCountingEntries", json);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Облікові записи успішно збережено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для збереження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_LoadCountingEntries)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("MyCountingEntries",null);
            if(!json.isEmpty())
            {
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CountingEntry>>() {}.getType();
                countingEntries.clear();
                countingEntries = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                RefreshList();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для завантаження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Код невозможно скопировать и посмотреть. Быстро решить проблему можно хранив дату в миллисекундах, а после воссоздать дату в нужном формате. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419374/android-convert-date-and-time-to-milliseconds

Answer (score -1):

GSON при сеарилизации обнуляет значение поля типа LocalDate.
Поэтому LocalDate нужно конвертировать в long и обратно